# Merging time series data in R zoo, joins are malformed

Tags: r, zoo

I am new to R, trying to merge 4 datasets using zoo, 2 datasets merge perfectly fine. 
However 2 other data sets give me o/p as follows:

### tmpA

```
2016-08-09 23:59:55 21.703 
2016-08-09 23:59:56 21.703 
2016-08-09 23:59:57 21.703 
2016-08-09 23:59:58 21.703 
2016-08-09 23:59:59 21.703 
2016-08-10 00:00:00 21.703
```

### tmpB

```
2016-08-09 23:59:52  24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:53  24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:54  24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:55  24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:56  24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:57  24.599
```

### Code

```
infoA.zoo <- read.zoo(infoA.dfH, header = TRUE, tz = "")
infoB.zoo <- read.zoo(infoB.dfH, header = TRUE, tz = "")
#dfH is data.frame 
#I am discretizing it over 1 sec.
merged = merge( tmpA, tmpB)
```

### Output

```
Date                      A              B
2016-08-09 23:59:56         NA      24.600
2016-08-09 23:59:57    21.703           NA
2016-08-09 23:59:57         NA      24.599
2016-08-09 23:59:58    21.703           NA
2016-08-09 23:59:59    21.703           NA
2016-08-10 00:00:00    21.703           NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reproduce your issue, but everything works fine. The only thing I changed was, that I change in the `tmpA` and `tmpB` the seperator from space to ';' and quote the date string. Furthermore I add the parameter `sep=';'` to the `read.zoo` function.

**tmpA**

```
"2016-08-09 23:59:55";21.703 
"2016-08-09 23:59:56";21.703 
"2016-08-09 23:59:57";21.703 
"2016-08-09 23:59:58";21.703 
"2016-08-09 23:59:59";21.703 
"2016-08-10 00:00:00";21.703
```

**tmpB**

```
"2016-08-09 23:59:52";24.600
"2016-08-09 23:59:53";24.600
"2016-08-09 23:59:54";24.600
"2016-08-09 23:59:55";24.600
"2016-08-09 23:59:56";24.600
"2016-08-09 23:59:57";24.599
```

**R**

```
# Copy tmpA string to clipboard
X <- read.zoo('clipboard', tz="", sep=';')
# Copy tmpY string to clipboard
Y <- read.zoo('clipboard', tz="", sep=';')
merge(X,Y)
                     X      Y
 2016-08-09 23:59:52 24.600     NA
 2016-08-09 23:59:53 24.600     NA
 2016-08-09 23:59:54 24.600     NA
 2016-08-09 23:59:55 24.600 21.703
 2016-08-09 23:59:56 24.600 21.703
 2016-08-09 23:59:57 24.599 21.703
 2016-08-09 23:59:58     NA 21.703
 2016-08-09 23:59:59     NA 21.703
 2016-08-10 00:00:00     NA 21.703
```

Comment: Yes, converting the date to string from POSIXct, using format, fixed the issue. http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/strptime.html